# Limits in multivariable function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim \limits_{(x, y) \to (0,0)} {x^3 + \sin(x^2+y^2)\over{y^4 + \sin(x^2+y^2)}}$$

I don't visualize a limited function anywhere to evaluate this limit (by the way, I have the information that this limit does exist).

Comment: Convert to polar coordinates

Comment: hint $\sin(z) = z + \mathcal O(|z|^3)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this limit really exists, then so should the limit of each variable, one at a time. This is both a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of the overall $\mathbb{R}^2$ limit.

Look at $\lim \limits_{y \to 0} \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3+\sin(x^2+y^2)}{y^4+\sin(x^2+y^2)} = \lim \limits_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin(y^2)}{y^4 + \sin(y^2)}$. Now using the variable transformation $p=y^2$, this becomes $\lim \limits_{p \to 0^+} \frac{\sin p}{p^2 + \sin p} = \lim \limits_{p \to 0^+} \frac{\frac{\sin p}{p}}{p + \frac{\sin p}{p}}$ and because we know $\lim \limits_{p \to 0^+} \frac{\sin p}{p} = 1$, the limit expression simplifies to $\frac{1}{0 + 1} = 1$.

On the other hand, $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} \lim \limits_{y \to 0} \frac{x^3+\sin(x^2+y^2)}{y^4+\sin(x^2+y^2)} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3 + \sin(x^2)}{\sin(x^2)} = \lim \limits_{x \to 0} x\frac{x^2}{\sin(x^2)} + 1$ and this is just $0 \times 1 + 1 = 1$.

Since both the permutations of limits exist and are equal, the limit in question exists too and is equal to the common value, i.e. $1$.

Comment: Why is the common value 0? Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: You're right. My bad!